# JAXB-Gen classes not getting added to class path

Tags: java, reflection, jaxb2

I am working on a project whose input is XSD.From the input XSD jaxb classes will be generated in a particular package.

There is reflection class which will create class from the ObjectFactory.java (JAXB generated).

```
Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("pkg.ObjectFactory");
```

But its throwing class not found exception.
Refreshing the excipse project by right clicking on it resolving the exception.

How to solve this problem automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Though wait for an eclipse-only answer too, maybe you should consider having a nice build infrastructure like **maven**. If you reached a size where would like to draw the build system in separate parts and pin it on the wall.

I am in favour of many independantly versioned (sub)projects. An explicit structure is best done with a **maven** build infrastructure, available for all IDEs. Then a project might generate the JAXB source classes, and the main project might *depend* on that project.